# Initializing constants class from resource file: possible?

Tags: spring, spring-3

I know that I can put my resources in a properties file and then associate class attributes to values with:

```
@Value("${batch-size}")
private Integer batchSize;
```

those values, however, are not constants so I was just wondering if it was possible to attain something like that:

```
public class RuntimeConstants{

        @Value("${batch-size}")
        private static final Integer batchSize; //this gives me a compiler error as java 
                                   //expects this attribute to be initialized in some way
}
```

Comment: Add the error message!

Comment: It is just a matter of initialization: if you declare an attribute as "final" java expects it is initialized in some way, as annotation is not recognized as valid initialization compiler complains about that.

Comment: While Spring may find a way to inject such a value, it is not compliant with Java since a constant has to be set, so the compiler fails. This is simply not possible.